# Make me a hexagon!

Tags: lateral-thinking, geometry, letters

I came in my office this morning, and there was a piece of paper on my computer screen where I could read:

> Make me a hexagon!

On my desk, there were four plastic letters: **t**, **a**, **n** and **h**. **All lowercase**.

I don't know who in the world is challenging me early in the morning, but of course I'm gonna make you a hexagon!

Flipping the paper on my screen, I could read:

> Your goal is to arrange the letters to make a hexagon. This hexagon will not have curved sides. The letters can't be flipped over or stacked, but rotating them is allowed.

... Well, then let me get my coffee first. What about **you go ahead and solve it first**? I'll catch up!

Comment: Can you clarify the phrase "This hexagon will only have straight lines"? What does it mean to "have straight lines"?

Comment: has to be regular?

Comment: @Matsmath Is "no curved sides" better?

Comment: Is the hexagon made up of only letters? And only lower case?

Comment: @Techidiot I'll let you think about it for a while, that's too many questions.

Comment: @Techidiot But yes, I specified lower case.

Comment: @Downvoter why the downvote? Please explain why do you think this puzzle is bad for you, it helps the OP to make better ones...

Comment: @IAmInPLS-Thanks that clears the question.

Comment: I definitely thought that with the letters spelling tanh, this was going to have a mathematical solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about

> turning the "n" upside down and spelling "utah"? The US state of Utah is a (nonconvex, ~spherical) hexagon.

This is a slightly unsatisfying answer (though I suspect it's the intended one) because

> the borders of the state of Utah *are* curved; lying on the surface of an approximate sphere, how could they not be?

Comment: I like your answer. However, I feel like there is *too much of* lateral jump interpreting your answer as a hexagon. Well... so, I am not explaining my concerns very well. My point is that you do *not* provide a hexagon, as wished by the OP, but rather you provide *something* which in turn *can be* interpreted as a hexagon.

Comment: @Matsmath That's why this is tagged lateral-thinking...

Comment: @Gareth Well, in three dimensions, yes, but in two dimensions, [they don't seem to be curved](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Utah/@39.4839433,-113.8062983,7z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x874c6bc78f13f9cd:0xbddf4aa56cd7463f!8m2!3d39.3209801!4d-111.0937311) (or very slightly).

Comment: They're close to straight on a Mercator projection, or any other that makes lines of latitude and longitude straight. But not quite! There's a kink in the eastern border, for historical reasons of some sort.

Comment: maybe this is why you answer others but not my question about "regular hexagon" @IAmInPLS xD

Comment: @lois6b Exactly!

Answer (score 11):

The solution:

> [image]

Because:

> Hex, "a" *gone*
>
>  Instead of building an Hexagon (geometric figure) I use the word "Hexagon" and pronunciation "hex" + "a" + "gone"  with a little bit of *creativity*
>  I form the word "hex" with the existing "h", the "e" is an "a" rotated 180 deg and the "x" is the "t" rotated -45 deg

Comment: I don't get this... Can you kindly over-explain your solution to non-native dummies like myself? Also, in OP there are two parts emphasized in **bold face** font. Are those parts covered by your solution? If so, then how?

Comment: But the "a" is there. The "n" is gone.

Comment: @FrodCube yeah, but the "a" is now an "e" .. ^^'

Comment: @lois6b Even if you count the "a" as gone, the "n" is gone even more and not mentioned in your solution. Apart from this you convinced me :)

Comment: Nice try, but no cookie for you :-)

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

> A hut

Why?

> Take outline of regular huts in a corner view and it gives you a hexagon.
>
>  e.g. [here](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/little-elevated-wooden-hut-jungle-village-landscape-element-cool-colorful-vector-illustration-stylized-geometric-cartoon-design-77193792.jpg)   and 
>  [here](http://trackingwonder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Bali-hut-thatched-roof.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Throw the plastic letters in the trash.

Take the note and use scissors to cut the words "a hexagon" out. Throw the rest of the paper in the trash.

Now all of the letters present have been arranged to make "a hexagon".